# Multivariable Substitution Rule VS Pullback of Volume Forms

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms

Let $d\mathbf{x} = dx^1\wedge \cdots \wedge dx^n$ be the volume form on $U\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ and smooth $c : [a_1,b_1]\times\cdots\times [a_n,b_n] \to U$, $\mathbf{t} = (t_1,\dots,t_n) \mapsto \mathbf{x} = \mathbf{c}(\mathbf{t}) = (c^1(t_1,\dots,t_n),\dots,c^n(t_1,\dots,t_n))$.

I’ve encountered the following two formulae:

*Multivariable Substitution Rule*: 
$$d\mathbf{x} = d\mathbf{c} = \vert det\left((D\mathbf{c})_\mathbf{t}\right) \vert d\mathbf{t}$$

*Pullback of Volume Forms*: 
$$c^*(d\mathbf{x}) = d\mathbf{c} = det\left((D\mathbf{c})_\mathbf{t}\right) d\mathbf{t} $$

$(D\mathbf{c})_\mathbf{t}$ is the total derivative of $\mathbf{c}$ at $\mathbf{t}$.

My question is, are these two formulae referring to different things? It feels like these two equations are talking about the same thing, but then why does one have an absolute value on the Jacobian determinant?

I’m trying to understand this so I can prove that integrals of differential forms only flip signs under a re-parameterisation that reverses orientation.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they essentially refer to the same thing. As you can guess, this has something to do with keeping signs consistent. Consider the effect of switching the order of variables in integration. Fubini says this is okay, right?

Let's just simply integrate with the variables being $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^2$. In the case where I do regular Riemann integration with substitution, $dxdy = dydx$ so there's no sign change from the "differential". But if we took *only* the determinant, then notice that changing the order of $x$ and $y$ multiplies the determinant by $-1$ (because we switch two columns which changes the sign of the determinant). So to keep the value the same, we take the absolute value of the determinant.

How does this work in the case of differential forms? We know that $dx \wedge dy = - dy \wedge dx$ so we have one sign change from here. To "counteract" it, we don't take the absolute value of the determinant. So we have two sign switches per variable switch, so the overall integral remains the same.

Comment: Then am I correct to say that the two refer to the same thing, except the first is in Riemann integration and the latter in integration of differential forms?

Comment: Also, your claim that integrals of differential forms remain the same under change of variables, correct me if I’m wrong but don’t integrals flip signs under a re-parameterisation of the domain that reverses orientation?

Comment: I didn’t say the integral stays the same under an arbitrary change of variables, just a switch in the order of integration. A change of variables changes the integral for both Riemann and differential forms (but by different means)

Comment: I’m not understanding what you mean by “changes the integral”? Are you referring to the expression of the integral or its value?

Comment: My bad, I'm referring to the value of the integral. To summarize what I mean, a switch in the order of integration doesn't affect the value of either the Riemann integral or the integral of differential forms. An orientation-reversing parametrization however will change the sign of both integrals, by affecting different things. In the "regular" Riemann integral, the bounds reverse to give a negative number. In the integration of differential forms, it drops out from the negative sign in the Jacobian determinant.

Answer (score 1):

If both formulas are correct, but lead to different results, they have to be about different things. The crux is in the notation: In the first formula $d{\bf x}$ and $d{\bf t}$ denote the unsigned "volume element" associated to Lebesgue measure in ${\mathbb R}^n$, whereas in the second formula your $d{\bf x}$ as well as $d{\bf t}=dt_1\wedge\ldots\wedge dt_n$ denote the volume form defined in terms of exterior algebra. The latter comes with a sign, and your formula takes care of that.

For myself I use the letter $d$ for signed things and ${\rm d}$ for unsigned ones. E.g., I write
$${\rm vol}(B)=\int_B 1\>{\rm d}({\bf x})\ .$$

Comment: (Sigh) I thought differential forms are meant to be an alternative approach to multivariable calculus. So why do all the texts I read keep using results from other approaches (Ordinary Multivariable, Lebesgue Integrals)? Can an exposition not be done independently?

Comment: Differential forms are not an "alternative" approach to multivariable calculus, but a geometrically uptuned and more sophisticated one. Students have to go through different stages of sophistication in all sorts of topics.

Comment: I see that ‘alternative’ is not the right word. What I meant was: I thought differential forms are meant to be a reformulation of multivariable calculus that is more general, from which theorems of multivariable calculus are derived as special cases rather than using these special cases to prove more general results?

Answer (score 1):

This question kind of baffles me too. I think the pullback statement is a well-defined, correct statement of equality between the two forms on the domain space (parameterized by **t**). This can be integrated over a desired region $R$ of the domain. If we want to work over the range, we use the theorem:
$$\int_{R} {\bf c}^*(d{\bf x}) = \int_{{\bf c}(R)} d{\bf x}$$
(This assumes $\bf{c}$
is orientation preserving. Otherwise, you need to
negate.)

I think the "multivariate rule" is a mnemonic that can be used *as part of* calculating an integral using variable substitution. But it does not describe a well-defined, correct statement of equality of two forms. (If it did, where does it live, the domain or the range? If it did, then why do you need to change the limits of integration when you wrap both sides by the integral sign?)

Regardless, what is formally true is that
$$ 
\int_R \det(D{\bf c})\, d{\bf t} =
\int_{{\bf c}(R)} d{\bf x} 
$$
where $D({\bf c})$ is the Jacobian matrix.
(This assumes $\bf{c}$
is orientation preserving. Otherwise, you need to
negate.)